# Set specific frame as thumbnail for video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I just want some confirmation, because I have the sneaking suspicion that I wont be able to do what I want to do, given that I already ran into some errors about ffmpeg not being able to overwrite the input file. I still have some hope that what I want to do is some kind of exception, but I doubt it.

I already used ffmpeg to extract a specific frame into its own image file, I've set the thumbnail of a video with an existing image file, but I can't seem to figure out how to set a specific frame from the video as the thumbnail. I want to do this without having to extract the frame into a separate file and I don't want to create an output file, I want to edit the video directly and change the thumbnail using a frame from the video itself. Is that possible?

Comment: Not possible with `ffmpeg` as it is unable to perform in-place editing.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off asking it in IRC zeronode #ffmpeg-devel.
I'd look at "-ss 33.5" or a more precise filter "-vf 'select=gte(n,1000)'"  both will give same or very similar result at 30 fps video.

You can pipe the image out to your own process via pipe if you like of course without saving it : "ffmpeg ... -f jpeg -|..."